# Pandas: How to check whether the first "n" elements of a string contain a substring?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I know how to use the `Pandas.Series.str.contains()` methods to check if a substring is present in another substring.

However, I'm wondering, how do we check whether the first "n" elements of a Pandas Series.str contains the substring?

Here is an example from some glycans I am working with:

```
Neu5Aca2-6Galb1-4GlcNAcb1-3Galb1-4GlcNAcb1-6(Galb1-3)GalNAca-Sp14
Neu5Aca2-6(Neu5Aca2-3Galb1-3)GalNAca-Sp14
Neu5Aca2-3Galb1-4GlcNAcb1-2Mana1-6(Neu5Aca2-6Galb1-4GlcNAcb1-2Mana1-3)Manb1-4GlcNAcb1-4GlcNAcb-Sp12
GalNAca1-3(Fuca1-2)Galb1-3GalNAca1-3(Fuca1-2)Galb1-4GlcNAcb-Sp0
```

I am currently doing `str.contains()` to check whether `a(2-3)` or `a(2-6)` occur in the name, but the third example is one where `a2-6` occurs both in the beginning and at the middle.

My goal is to isolate the substring `a2-3` from the first `n` letters in each string. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to build a regex that matches your data more cleanly, but you can search for a substring in the first n characters of a string using the `str.slice()` method

```
In [128]: glycans
Out[128]: 
0    Neu5Aca2-6Galb1-4GlcNAcb1-3Galb1-4GlcNAcb1-6(G...
1            Neu5Aca2-6(Neu5Aca2-3Galb1-3)GalNAca-Sp14
2    Neu5Aca2-3Galb1-4GlcNAcb1-2Mana1-6(Neu5Aca2-6G...
3    GalNAca1-3(Fuca1-2)Galb1-3GalNAca1-3(Fuca1-2)G...
dtype: object

In [134]: glycans.str.slice(0,10).str.contains('a2-3')
Out[134]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: You can also use standard string slice notation like `.str[:10]`, but it amounts to the same thing.